# Importing images from Slack

Tags: rocket.chat

Slack exports its data as a ZIP, without images.
It uses public URLs instead, so on my imported chanels inside Rocket, I see only links to slack instead of the inline images.
Is there any way to instruct Rocket to automatically download all those images and embed them in the channels?
What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, RocketChat cannot automatically download and import the Slack attachments. There are several 3rd party and open source tools to separately download the referenced attachments in the Slack export files. One example is [slack-advanced-exporter](https://github.com/grundleborg/slack-advanced-exporter).

Then, you have all the attachments in a separate folder. This is still not enough to import the Slack messages with the attachments into RocketChat. An additional converter would be helpful to replace the urls in the Slack JSONs with the correct file links and create the correct folder structure for the attachments. As far as I know, this additional converter is still missing (at least in the open source landscape).

Comment: There is an open issue requesting this functionality from the slack-advanced-exporter. Feel free to like this issue to show that it would still be helpful. 

https://github.com/grundleborg/slack-advanced-exporter/issues/14#issue-480673528